# Adding unicoded icon inside dataProvider amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I am trying to add a green or red arrow next to the label.I have added customBullet field for my amchart but I could't insert the unicoded arrow inside 
dataProvider. Here is the codes :

```
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("avaragediv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",

    "rotate": true,
    "marginBottom": 50,
    "dataProvider": [{
        "age": "Average Opened",
        "male": -0.8,
        "female": 0.3,
        "bullet":"<text>&#9650;</text>",
    }, {
        "age": "Average Effort",
        "male": -0.2,
        "female": 0.3,

    }, {
        "age": "Average Speed",
        "male": -0.3,
        "female": 0.6
    }, {
        "age": "Average Handle",
        "male": -0.5,
        "female": 0.8
    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "male",
        "title": "Monthly",
        "customBulletField": "bullet",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "clustered": false,
        "labelFunction": function (item) {
            return Math.abs(item.values.value);
        },
        "balloonFunction": function (item) {
            return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
        }
    }, {
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "female",
        "title": "Weekly",
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "clustered": false,
        "labelFunction": function (item) {
            return Math.abs(item.values.value);
        },
        "balloonFunction": function (item) {
            return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
        }
    }],
    "categoryField": "age",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "axisAlpha": 0
    },
    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "labelFunction": function (value) {
            return Math.abs(value) + '%';
        },
        "guides": [{
            "value": 0,
            "lineAlpha": 0.2
        }]
    }],
    "balloon": {
        "fixedPosition": true
    },
    "allLabels": [{
        "text": "Weekly",
        "x": "28%",
        "y": "85%",
        "bold": true,
        "align": "middle"
    }, {
        "text": "Monthly",
        "x": "75%",
        "y": "85%",
        "bold": true,
        "align": "middle"
    }],

});
```

Encoded arrow is &#9650 . How can I do that? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodotu/v2zm211g/)

Comment: create fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `customBulletField` expects a path to an image (bitmap or SVG), not Unicode text.

Comment: so how can I add an unicoded character to labels?